# Decompress folder.tar.gz with files inside

Tags: tar, zstd

I'm trying to decompress folder.tar.gz which was previously compressed with zstd, so I did:

```
unzstd folder.tar.gz.zst
```

Now if I try to decompress by using:

```
tar -xvf folder.tar.gz
```

It will decompress two big files inside some folder joined together.

Apparently the path which was compressed was: `/opt/local/data/file1.log` and `file2.log`.

After decompressing I get `data` folder joined by size of "file1 and file2.log".

Comment: Normally you would need option `-z` to extract a `.tar.gz`. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output of `tar tvf folder.tar.gz` and `tar tvzf folder.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 2):

`tar.gz.zstd` suggests you have a tar archive compressed with gz and the result compressed again with zstd.

To confirm, you can use `file`:

```
$ file file.tar.gz.zstd
file.tar.gz.zstd: Zstandard compressed data (v0.8+), Dictionary ID: None
$ unzstd < file.tar.gz.zstd | file -
/dev/stdin: gzip compressed data, from Unix
$ unzstd < file.tar.gz.zstd | gunzip | file -
/dev/stdin: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

To list the contents of the `tar` archive, you can use libarchive's `bsdtar` which should be able to detect the double-compression and decompress on the fly:

```
bsdtar tvf file.tar.gz.zstd
```

Or with other tar implementation, do it by hand:

```
unzstd < file.tar.gz.zstd | gunzip | tar tvf -
```

To extract, it's the same, you just replace `t` with `x`.

If you want to remove the redundant compression, you can do:

```
unzstd file.tar.gz.zstd
```

And get a `file.tar.gz`, or do:

```
unzstd < file.tar.gz.zstd | gunzip | zstd > file.tar.zstd
```

To get a `file.tar.zstd`.

Answer (score 1):

That file is (reading the extensions in order) is a `tar` file compressed using `gzip` which itself is compressed by `zstd`.
Eg. double compressed: `gzip` inside `zstd`.

This is not common practice, maybe you changed the extension your self or the creator made an error?

The proper extension for a `zstd` compressed `tar` file is `.tzst`...

I would suggest to check the file using the `file` command

You should also be able to do `tar -xvf folder.tzst` when it actually is a "`zstd` compressed `tar` file" but just has wrong extensions, by just renaming the file...